# EOM for Double Pendulum using Newton's Laws of Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

Whenever I've searched up the derivation of the EOM for the [double pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum), it has been done using the Lagrangian and generalized coordinates. Is there any method to get the EOM for the double pendulum using Newton's laws and *cartesian* coordinates? If so, can someone explain? b

Comment: In principle it can be done since the Newtonian and Lagrangian formalisms are equivalent, but why do you want to take the trouble doing it in a more difficult manner (Newtonian) when an easier method for solving it exists?

Comment: You set up the geometry, two coordinates per point mass, then solve for geometric constraints and use force vectors. It's just geometry. At the end of the day you will arrive at exactly the same equations of motion as with Lagrange and Hamilton. The advantage of the other two formalisms is that they let you find conserved quantities and constants of motion more easily, IF they exist. In this case they don't as far as I know and the system is chaotic. It is, of course, chaotic and nonintegrable in any coordinate representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Newton's laws of motion, for a double pendulum, you would have to explicitly include the tension in the equations of motion. You would have to use a diagram, like the one shown [here](https://rotations.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/double-pendulum.png) find out the forces acting on the two pendulum bobs. From the image, is clear that we have the constraints
$$|\mathbf{r}_1|=l_1, |\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1|=l_2, z_1=z_2=0$$
Doing the force analysis mentioned above, one finds that the force acting on the bob 1 is
$$\mathbf{F}_1=T_2\frac{\mathbf{r}_2-{\mathbf{r}_1}}{l_2}-T_1\frac{\mathbf{r}_1}{l_1}+m_1\mathbf{g},$$
while the force acting on bob 2 is
$$\mathbf{F}_2=-T_2\frac{\mathbf{r}_2-{\mathbf{r}_1}}{l_2}+m_2\mathbf{g}.$$
The equations of motion are therefore,
$$m_1\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_1=T_2\frac{\mathbf{r}_2-{\mathbf{r}_1}}{l_2}-T_1\frac{\mathbf{r}_1}{l_1}+m_1\mathbf{g}$$
$$m_2\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_2=-T_2\frac{\mathbf{r}_2-{\mathbf{r}_1}}{l_2}+m_2\mathbf{g}.$$
From this, it should be straightforward to express the equations of motion in Cartesian coordinates, and we can use the constraint equations to reduce this to a system with two degrees of freedom. I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Good answer. But what are $z_1$ and $z_2$? Those are not clear from the diagram as far as I can tell. Also, is it possible for you import the diagram to this site so the link does not go dead?

Comment: Either the OP likes Differential Algebraic Equations or this is not a good answer

Answer (score 2):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

**NEWTON equation of motion double pendulum**

starting with the position vectors to the masses
\begin{align*}
 &\b R_1=L_1\begin{bmatrix}
          \sin(\theta_1) \\
           \cos(\theta_1)\\
        \end{bmatrix}
\quad, 
\b R_2=\b R_1+L_2\begin{bmatrix}
          \sin(\theta_2) \\
           \cos(\theta_2)\\
        \end{bmatrix}        
\end{align*}
from here the velocities
\begin{align*}
 &\b v_1=\frac{\partial \b R_1}{\partial \theta_1}{\dot{\theta}_1}\\
 &\b v_2=\frac{\partial \b R_2}{\partial \theta_1}{\dot{\theta}_1}
 +\frac{\partial \b R_2}{\partial \theta_2}{\dot\theta_2}
\end{align*}
and the accelerations
\begin{align*}
 &\b a_1=\frac{\partial \b R_1}{\partial \theta_1}{\ddot{\theta}_1}+
 \frac{\partial \b v_1}{\partial \theta_1}{\dot{\theta}_1}:=
 \b J_{11}\,\ddot{\theta}_1+\b z_1\tag 1
 \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 &\b a_2=\frac{\partial \b R_2}{\partial \theta_1}{\ddot{\theta}_1}
 +\frac{\partial \b R_2}{\partial \theta_2}{\ddot\theta_2}+
 \frac{\partial \b v_2}{\partial \theta_1}{\dot{\theta}_1}
 +\frac{\partial \b v_2}{\partial \theta_2}{\dot\theta_2}
 :=\b J_{21}\,\ddot{\theta}_1+\b J_{22}\,\ddot{\theta}_2 +\b z_2\tag 2
\end{align*}
Newton second Law
\begin{align*}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   m_1 & 0 \\
   0 & m_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \b a_1 \\
   \b a_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
  - m_1\,g \\
 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   -m_2\,g \\
 \end{bmatrix}+\b F_c
\end{align*}
where $~\b F_c~$ are the constraint forces

with equations (1) and (2)
\begin{align*}
 \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
   m_1 & 0 \\
   0 & m_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\b M}\,\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
  \b J_{11} & 0 \\
   \b J_{21} & \b J_{22} \\
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\b J}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \ddot{\theta}_1 \\
   \ddot{\theta}_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}=
 \underbrace{ -\begin{bmatrix}
    m_1\,\b z_1 \\
    m_2\,\b z_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}-
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   m_1\,g \\
 \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   m_2\,g \\
 \end{bmatrix}}_{F}+\b F_c\tag 3
 \end{align*}

to eliminate the constraint forces $~\b F_c~$from equation (3) , you multiply equation (3) from the left with
$~\b J^T~$
\begin{align*}
  \b J^T\,\b M\,\b J\,\begin{bmatrix}
   \ddot{\theta}_1 \\
   \ddot{\theta}_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}=\b J^T\, \b F\quad\Rightarrow\,
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \ddot{\theta}_1 \\
   \ddot{\theta}_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}=\left[\b J^T\,\b M\,\b J\right]^{-1}\,\b J^T\, \b F
 \end{align*}

---

Example :

**2D Pendulum , constraint force elimination**

constraint equation

$$x^2+y^2=L^2$$
form here
$$x\,\dot x+y\,\dot y=0\tag A$$
or
$$\underbrace{ \begin{bmatrix}
   x & y \\
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\b C_C}\,\begin{bmatrix}
                  \dot{x} \\
                  \dot{y}\\
                \end{bmatrix}=0$$
take $~\dot x~$ the generalized velocity coordinate, thus from equation (A) you obtain

$$\dot y=-\frac xy\,\dot x\quad\Rightarrow\\ 
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \dot{x} \\
   \dot{y}\\
 \end{bmatrix}=
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   -\frac xy\\
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\b J}\dot x$$

the constraint force is
$~\b F_c=\b C^T_C\,\b F_g~$ where $~F_g~$ is the generalized constraint force.

$$ \b J^T\,\b C^T_C=\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & -\frac xy \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
               x \\
               y \\
             \end{bmatrix}=0\quad\surd$$
this means that if you "work" with generalized coordinate you can ignore the constraint forces

Comment: How does the $\mathbf{J}^T \mathbf{F}_c$ term go away?

Comment: $ ~\mathbf J^T\,\mathbf F_c~$ is equal zero because the D'Alembert Prinzip.

Comment: This might be the case, but it is not clear to me how. Can you explain how? And further the D'Alembert Principle is effectively the same as the Lagrange equations of motion ($[\frac{d}{dt}\frac{}{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_i} - \frac{\partial T}{\partial q_i} = Q_i$ when $Q_i = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}$, see Goldstein Eq. 1.52), but this is what OP asked to avoid.

Comment: @hft i worte for you simple example, but it is also true for general case . this Approche is applying in "Multi Body System (MBS)" to obtain the equations of motion numerically.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful!